# How do I get the filename of an open std::fs::File in Rust?

Tags: linux, file, rust

I have an open [`std::fs::File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html), and I want to get it's filename, e.g. as a `PathBuf`. How do I do that?

The simple solution would be to just save the path used in the call to `File::open`. Unfortunately, this does not work for me. I am trying to write a program that reads log files, and the program that writes the logs keep changing the filenames as part of it's log rotation. So the file may very well have been renamed since it was opened. This is on Linux, so renaming open files is possible.

How do I get around this issue, and get the current filename of an open file?

Comment: Maybe you can find out via the contents of `/proc/self/fd`? I've never done anything like before, so not totally sure.

Comment: What would you like to do with the filename once you found it?

Comment: @SvenMarnach The files are numbered, with the one currently being written ending with `.0`, the one before that `.1` and so on. I want to find the number for my open file so I can figure out which file is the next. (And here I am going to run into the race condition you mention in your answer...) Thanks for good input, answer and edit! :-)

Comment: So you want to read all the log files in a directory? Maybe you should iterate the directory once using `read_dir()` or the `glob` crate, and open all files you find at that point in time. You are still subject to race conditions, but only once, and at the very beginning of the process.

Comment: @SvenMarnach That is a very clever idea. I will think about all this and maybe ask a new question about the race condition later on. Thanks again for all the input, I learned a lot from this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On a typical Unix filesystem, a file may have multiple filenames at once, or even none at all. The file metadata is stored in an *inode*, which has a unique *inode number*, and this inode number can be linked from any number of directory entries. However, there are no reverse links from the inode back to the directory entries.

Given an open `File` object in Rust, you can get the inode number using the [`ino()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.Metadata.html#method.ino). If you know the directory the log file is in, you can use [`std::fs::read_dir()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_dir.html) to iterate over all entries in that directory, and each entry will also have an [`ino()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.DirEntry.html#method.ino), so you can find the one(s) matching your open file object. Of course this approach is subject to race conditions – the directory entry may already be gone again once you try to do anything with it.

Answer (score 5):

On linux, files handles held by the current process can be found under `/proc/self/fd`. These look and act like symlinks to the original files (though I think they may technically be something else - perhaps someone who knows more can chip in).

You can therefore recover the (possibly changed) file name by constructing the correct path in `/proc/self/fd` using your file descriptor, and then following the symlink back to the filesystem.

This snippet shows the steps:

```rust
use std::fs::read_link;
use std::os::unix::io::AsRawFd;
use std::path::PathBuf;

// if f is your std::fs::File

// first construct the path to the symlink under /proc
let path_in_proc = PathBuf::from(format!("/proc/self/fd/{}", f.as_raw_fd()));

// ...and follow it back to the original file
let new_file_name = read_link(path_in_proc).unwrap();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Have you confirmed that this actually gives the changed name, and not the old one? I will try it out later and check! Thanks! :-)

Comment: At least on my machine, renaming an open file is reflected in the `/proc/*/fd`. I made a simple test program that created a file and then slept for a few seconds to give me time to rename it, then printed the new name, and things worked as expected.

Comment: Linux can track renames in most cases, but there are limits. For example, if you first add a new file name to the file (i.e. a hard link) and then remove the old one, you won't be able to find the new name.